# Google login with Azure AD vs Azure AD B2c

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2b

There are already many comparisons around Azure AD B2B and B2C, but none of them answer my question. As these technologies have many things in common, I am trying to identify what is best in my scenario.

We are building few web apps/apis that will be used by our company employees, our partners and also few external users with their google login. My company uses Azure AD and some partners have presence in Azure AD and some do not.

Few additional requirements are:

1. We want to host these application on a separate tenant, separate from our enterprise tenant.
2. Partners should be able to use not only the apps but also azure resources
3. Enable login with Social providers for external users (Google for now)
4. No requirement to use Office 365

This seems more like a B2C scenario, but can also be done by using Azure AD with B2B collaboration and Azure AD allows Google as one of the Identity providers. So what is the disadvantage of using Azure AD in this case?

Comment: I like to think that any environment where you specifically choose who gets to use your applications should be considered a *B2B* scenario. Also I don't think you can give access to Azure Resources via B2C - i.e. I don't know of any way to "log into the Azure Portal via B2C". I see no reason to use B2C unless your partners want to be able to sign up without your supervision.

Comment: @AlexAIT thanks for the point on unsupervised sign-up. We may run into other social providers, so that's what made me think about this comparison. I am not sure if Azure AD support other social providers as part of Organizational Relationships anytime soon.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to download [this **Enabling Partners, Suppliers, and Customers to Access
Applications with Azure Active Directory** whitepaper](https://aka.ms/aadexternalidentities) that explains how applications can be built to implement an authentication experience for employees, partners, and other external users.

The Woodgrove Groceries [app](https://woodgrovegroceriesb2c.azurewebsites.net/) and [code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-external-identities-woodgrove-demo) demonstrate this.

Answer (score 0):

B2C is designed for customers, not employees i.e. people who are not typically domain-joined and have e.g. a Gmail address not a company.onmicrosoft.com one.

B2C does not allow any SaaS interaction (not just O365).

When you start talking about "partners", that's B2B and Azure AD would be the way to go.

Comment: As I mentioned, these apps must be on a separate tenant. In this case, all the employees are nothing but consumers for these apps. I agree with you that partners are B2B but if the partner is not on Azure then there is no B2B. Also, considering these partners as Consumers they can still use their corporate credentials to login into my app. Thank you for pointing out about SaaS Integration.

Comment: I just created a B2C tenant (using my personal account) and added a user from another tenant (my corporate account) as a user for Azure Portal from Azure AD blade (not B2C) and able to login to azure portal. Does this mean I can create a B2C tenant and still use B2B for portal? I am confused.